# By a bash script executed in a local computer run a command (with sudo privileges) on a remote server

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, redirect, sshpass

#### Run a command on a remote system from a local computer

I need to execute a command on a remote lubuntu 22.04 system by a ssh connection, but without open a shell. **This instruction will be executed inside a script.** The script is executed on my local system (that has an other Ubuntu distribution installed). I have found that I can do it, with success, executing on the local system the following script:

```
# define a variable which stored the password
MYPASSWORD='mypassword'

sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "cp /home/myuser/file1 /path/to/dest/"
```

In the command I have used `sshpass` (which is installed on my local system) to avoid the input of the password for the user `myuser` needed to authenticate the ssh session.

#### My needs

I have also to execute a `cp` command as the previous but the destination for the file is a subfolder of `/etc` and this need `sudo` privileges. So the script becomes:

```
MYPASSWORD='mypassword'

sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "cp /home/myuser/file1 /path/to/dest/"

sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "sudo -S cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/"
```

If I execute the script, the last command of the script outputs the following request:

```
[sudo] password for myuser:
```

So the script stops its execution and waits for the `sudo` password.
**I don't want this!**

#### An attempt of mine

If I execute the command:

```
> echo mypassword | sudo -S -s cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/
```

directly **on a terminal of the remote system** it works and copies `file1` to `/etc/sub/folder/` without asking the `sudo` password.

But if I execute the following command **on my local system**:

```
sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "echo mypassword | sudo -S -s cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/"
```

it doesn't work!

#### My question

Is there a way to avoid the input of the password for `sudo` by keyboard? Is it possible to send the password automatically?

Comment: First of all, you should always prefer SSH Keys to `sshpass` for passwordless login. If this is not possible for whatever reason, always use a password file with permissions `600`, then you can run `sshpass -f /path/to/passwordfile ssh  ...` Regarding the `sudo` password: Do you need to copy always to the same directory? Then, you should rethink your permissions.

Comment: Generally, for me it seems you have a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and your proposed solution is not the best option for what you really want to do.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks for your suggestions. About `sudo`: I need to copy `file1` from `/home/myuser/` to `/etc/sub/folder` and in this case I have to use `sudo`. I don't want and I can't change the configuration of the remote system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround/solution.

#### Using a file that temporarily stores the password for `sudo`

I have modified the script executed in the local system by adding some commands showed below:

- creation of a text file in the folder of the remote system by the `echo` command; the file is called `password.txt` and contains only the password (`"mypassword"`) for the user `myuser`.
- the file `password.txt` is direct as input to the `sudo` command by the operator `<`.
- execution of the command `sudo -S < /home/myuser/password.txt cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/`
- deletion of the file /home/myuser/password.txt from the remote system

This solution is used in a secure development environment so not break any security constraint.

#### The new script

With this instructions the script executed in the local system becomes:

```
MYPASSWORD='mypassword'

# creation of the file password.txt on the home folder of the remote system
sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "echo $MYPASSWORD > /home/myuser/password.txt"

# execution of the command which needs the sudo privileges (on remote system)
sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "sudo -S < /home/myuser/password.txt cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/"
# The '<' directs file passowrd.txt as input to sudo   ===========================

# deletion of the file password.txt
sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 rm /home/myuser/password.txt
```

#### Suppress the output of `sudo -S`

I have found an other improvement which allows to suppress the output (`[sudo] password for myuser:`) of the command `sudo -S` which is sent from ssh to the local system.
It is enaugh to use the operator `&>` and the `/dev/null` device as showed below:

```
sshpass -p $MYPASSWORD ssh myuser@192.168.1.1 "sudo -S \
  < /home/myuser/password.txt cp /home/myuser/file1 /etc/sub/folder/" &> /dev/null
```

**Note** In my local system suppression of output `[sudo] password for myuser:` works by following redirections:

- `&>/dev/null`
- `>&/dev/null`

and this is normal because previous operators are equivalent (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/335396/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) on SuperUser).

The suppression **does not work** by the following redirection:

- `>/dev/null`